# How to locate an element that doesn't have element name using xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hi can anyone let me know if it is possible to locale an element that doesn't have element name using xpath? The element I want to click is a 'x' button beside a label, and it doesn't have a name, I find it is "::after" when I inspect element in browser.

```
::after
```

[image: the 'x' button doesn't have a name]

Comment: `::after` elements do not really exist in the DOM, you cannot address them with XPath (they are called "pseudo-elements" for a reason).

Comment: Locator for fd-token tag should work for you. Try //fd-token[@id='token']. Since that tag is getting closed after where you have highlighted. Hope this might work :)

Comment: @BeingAutomation, no unfortunately this won't work, it would only click on the text label, that doesn't give the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get element using JavaScript. Example how to get `content` from pseudo element.

```
element = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.business-in-area")))
element_content = driver.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':before').getPropertyValue('content');", element)
```

Comment: Hi @Sers could you give me example that is specific to this example, i don't know what is "span.business-in-area" for? And what is ":before' used? I thought it would probably be '::after'?

Comment: You should replace `span.business-in-area` with selector for your element, and replace `before` with `after`